# Must difference_type be comparable?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

The requirements for random access iterators are found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). On this page, you will see that for any two `RandIt`s, `a` and `b`, `a<b` and `a-b` are both legal c++. `a-b` returns a `difference_type`.

In my code, I want to compute `a<b`, but instead of comparing `a` and `b`, I want to compare `a-first` and `b-first`. This requires two things:

1. `difference_type`s are comparable.
2. `(a-first < b-first) == (a < b)`.

It would be easy to implement comparison of `difference_type`s as satisfying (2), but I can't tell if this is required by the standard. Do (1) and (2) hold?

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements#iterator.iterators-2.2

Comment: @NathanOliver there are lots of signed integer types. Does it mean ```signed int``` necessarily, or a signed one of [these](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), or can a user define their own "signed integer" type? I can imagine plenty of ```difference_type```s that don't behave like single integers.

Comment: See [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental#1).  Its doesn't call it out specifically but it would be weird if the standard signed integers are treated differently from the extended signed integer types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [standard requires `iterator_traits<It>::difference_type` to be a "signed integer type"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/iterator.iterators#2.2) (or `void`). This statement is to be taken literally. [[basic.fundamental]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.fundamental#1) defines a number of types which are "integer types" and a subset of them to be "signed integer types".

These are the *only* "signed integer types" in C++. You may create types which *act* like "signed integer types," but the standard clearly defines a specific set of functional types which fit this term. And your user-defined types aren't them.

So it's not your choice whether `difference_type` is "comparable" or not; all integer types are comparable because that's how C++ defines them.